# Binning Technique to discretize continues data

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, binning

I have a following data set,

Columns 1 through 6

```
1.0000         0    0.9954   -0.0589    0.8524    0.0231
1.0000         0    1.0000   -0.1883    0.9304   -0.3616
1.0000         0    1.0000   -0.0336    1.0000    0.0049
1.0000         0    1.0000   -0.4516    1.0000    1.0000
1.0000         0    1.0000   -0.0240    0.9414    0.0653
1.0000         0    0.0234   -0.0059   -0.0992   -0.1195
1.0000         0    0.9759   -0.1060    0.9460   -0.2080
     0         0         0         0         0         0
1.0000         0    0.9636   -0.0720    1.0000   -0.1433
```

I am trying to build decision tree using binary split one of the problem is data is continues and my current implementation become computationally intense by leaving the data as it is and doing the split. I must say this would be that bad if you are just building a one classifier.

In my case I am doing a ten-fold and increase classifiers from 5-50 (Bagging). I was thinking to do binning such way where data get bucket into 0.2 buckets but I realize there are negative numbers. I am using matlab for my implementation. I am a Matlab NewB and no sure if there are pre-define methods to handle scenarios like this.

Comment: Can you please try to write your problem a bit more clearly? If you stick to simple, short sentences that could improve this question a lot. I have tried to clear up the language of this question before  answering it, but there were things I could not understand. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure whether this solves your question completely, but if your problem is defining the 'buckets' dynamically you can do this:

```
% Find the minimum and maximum of the matrix
Mmin = min(M(:));
Mmax = max(M(:));

% Assume you have a matrix M with positive and negative values, and want it in bins of 0.2
buckets = Mmin:0.2:Mmax;

% OR assume you want to spread them equally over a fixed amount of bins, say 100
buckets = linspace(Mmin,100,Mmax);
```

EDIT:

Suppose you want to devide the matrix based on the values of one column, say 3, then you can do it like this:

```
% Define the relevant column as a vector for easy handling
v = M(:,3);

% Assume you want to spread them equally over a fixed amount of bins, say 100
buckets = linspace(min(v),100,max(v));
% Now see which column belongs in each bucket
bucket_idx = ones(size(v));
for i = 2:length(buckets)
    bucket_idx(v>buckets(i-1)&(v<buckets(i)) = i;
end
```

This tells you in which bucket each row belongs, it would be nicer to vectorize this but at the moment this is the quickest solution I can think of. I think you should be able to solve the rest of the problem once you know in which bucket everything belongs.

Comment: I like spreading it in equal number of buckets idea, any chance you could tell me how I can no convert original matrix to represent interms of bucket. I am using last column as label of the data. Thanks

Comment: Should not the label be 1/0 for binary trees? I see that the last column contains various floats... in case of continuous labels you are doing rather regression.

Comment: sorry didn't put the last column in my question. all together I have 34 columns in my matrix where 35th column is label wherer class1 = 1 class2 = 2

Comment: I have added an example of how to devide them into buckets based on one column.